# Split string column and extract second part in Python

Tags: python, pandas, split, extract

Let's say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": range(4), "price": ["15dollar/m2/day", "90dollar/m2/month", "18dollar/m2/day", "100dollar/m2/month"]})

       id               price
    0   0     15dollar/m2/day
    1   1   90dollar/m2/month
    2   2     18dollar/m2/day
    3   3  100dollar/m2/month
```

I would like to split column `price` into two new columns: `unit_price` and `price_unit` as below:

```
   id     unit_price  price_unit
0   0        15.0    dollar/m2/day
1   1        90.0    dollar/m2/month
2   2        18.0    dollar/m2/day
3   3       100.0    dollar/m2/month
```

This is my solution:

```
df['unit_price'] = df['price'].str.split('dollar').str[0].astype(float)
#df['unit_price'] = df['price'].str.extract('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', expand=False).astype(float)
df['price_unit'] = df['price'].str.split('dollar').str[1]
del df['price']
```

For the column `unit_price`, it works fine, but for `price_unit`, when i split by `dollar`, I got result as below which doesn't including character `dollar`, or if I use `df['price'].str.replace(r'\d', '')`, all numbers were removed. 
How could I do it correctly in Python? Thanks.

```
df['price_unit']
Out[474]: 
0      /m2/day
1    /m2/month
2      /m2/day
3    /m2/month
Name: price_unit, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex - `^` for start of string, `\d*\.\d+` for floats or `\d+` for integers and then for all another values by `.*`:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('price').str.extract('(?P<unit_price>^\d*\.\d+|^\d+)(?P<price_unit>.*)'))
print (df)
   id unit_price       price_unit
0   0         15    dollar/m2/day
1   1         90  dollar/m2/month
2   2         18    dollar/m2/day
3   3        100  dollar/m2/month
```

First solution is using `extract` and `replace` by numeric:

```
pat = '(^\d*\.\d+|^\d+)'
df['unit_price'] = df['price'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
df['price_unit'] = df.pop('price').str.replace(pat,'')
print (df)
   id unit_price       price_unit
0   0         15    dollar/m2/day
1   1         90  dollar/m2/month
2   2         18    dollar/m2/day
3   3        100  dollar/m2/month
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what `?P` stand for?

Comment: @ahbon - sure, if check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#extract-first-match-in-each-subject-extract) - it is for new columns names

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a string, why not keep it simple and add the dollar part yourself?

`df['price_unit'] = 'dollar' + df['price'].str.split('dollar').str[1]`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": range(4), "price": ["15dollar/m2/day", "90dollar/m2/month", "18dollar/m2/day", "100dollar/m2/month"]})

df['unit_price'] = df['price'].str.split('dollar').str[0].astype(float)
df['price_unit'] = 'dollar' + df['price'].str.split('dollar').str[1]

del df['price']

print(df)
```

---

```
   id  unit_price       price_unit
0   0        15.0    dollar/m2/day
1   1        90.0  dollar/m2/month
2   2        18.0    dollar/m2/day
3   3       100.0  dollar/m2/month
```

Comment: Thanks it works in this situation. But I think @jezrael's solution is more general in case if there are other money unit `yen`, `euro`, etc.

Comment: ah, yes. If the currency can change, that is indeed a more general solution.